# Как сделать запрос в БД, который будет выводить значения > 0?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД, в ней есть таблица `test`, в таблице присутствует столбец `power`, в столбце числа `0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...` и так далее.

Как сделать запрос к БД, который будет выводить значения таблицы, при условии что **они больше нуля**?

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT power FROM test WHERE type_tovar='type1'", $link);

if ($result == 0)
{
    echo '';
}
elseif ($result > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do
    {
        echo '
        <p>'.$row{"power"}.'</p>
        ';
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: `SELECT power FROM test WHERE type_tovar='type1' AND power > 0`. Но советую вам почитать про sql запросы и php. У вас ужасный во всех смыслах код. Включая использование устаревших расширений php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и замечание, буду учиться.

Answer (score 1):

В запросе к BD будет такое условие `where` :

```
WHERE type_tovar='type1' AND power > 0
```